# Terraform variable - This value does not have any attributes

Tags: terraform

having problems with a terraform variable use on a resource:

```
resource "mso_schema" "on_prem_and_aws" {
  name          = var.hybrid_schema.name
  template_name = var.hybrid_schema.template_name
  tenant_id     = mso_tenant.demo_tenant.id 
}
```

on the .tf vars file i have:

```
variable "hybrid_schema" {
  type    = string
  default = "streched"
}
```

Its giving the error:

Error: Unsupported attribute

on schema.tf line 25, in resource "mso_schema" "on_prem_and_aws":
25:   name          = var.hybrid_schema.name

This value does not have any attributes.

Error: Unsupported attribute

on schema.tf line 26, in resource "mso_schema" "on_prem_and_aws":
26:   template_name = var.hybrid_schema.template_name

This value does not have any attributes.

What am i missing here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hybrid_schema` is just a string value. If you want it to be `map` with keys of `name` and `template_name` it should be:

```
variable "hybrid_schema" {
  default = {
     name = "some name"
     template_name = "template name"
  }
}
```

Comment: @NunoMarques No problem. Glad it helped.